# Javascript - linux (crontab)

Tags: javascript, linux, cron

I'm making a web-service Job Scheduler, a bell actually that play a .wav file for each time input by the user. And I don't want to involve PHP in this project.
So, I'm gonna use JavaScript to do this project.

The question is:
How to write into a crontab file `crontab -e` with JavaScript?
Is it possible ?
So that I convert the logic of the time inputted by the user into a cronjob script which is like `* * * * * /command` with JavaScript and write it automatically into crontab file. How to write it automatically.

Comment: How do you plan to run your JavaScript? Classic ASP? Node JS? (I hope you aren't expecting JavaScript running in the web browser to be able to change the configuration of the computer hosting the HTTP server)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crontab

Comment: Are you trying to avoid PHP, per se, or are you trying to avoid creating a server-side API entirely?

Comment: @TheSpooniest exactly, is it possible ?

Comment: @Quentin why can't I ?

Comment: @YoksanHerlie — Imagine if my web browser could change the configuration of your online banking service's web server.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid PHP, you can create your server-side API in any programming language you want (even JavaScript, if you use something like node.js). But you can't avoid creating a server-side API of some kind: client-side JavaScript can make calls to URLs back on the server, but the server needs some way to understand what these calls mean.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Nodejs to run a shell command:

```
let process = require('child_process');
let cmd = "some command"
process.exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr){
    e && console.log('exec error: ' + e);
});
```

So you can write two crontab file `c1` and `c2`, then write codes to run commands like `crontab File path/to/c1` and `crontab File path/to/c2` automatically.